# How are 'by hands' and 'by hand' different?

Tags: expressions

In the sentence , is the expression 'by hands' right?
Shouldn't it be 'by hand'?
I understand 'by hand' means 'by a person not by a machine.
If both are OK how are they different?
Thanks in advance.

One solution is the Freeplay radio, which can be charged by hands.

Comment: I get 11 results on Google for ["charged by hands"](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&ei=Xv3BWq_AJon1UNDKq2A&q=%22charged+by+hands%22&oq=%22charged+by+hands%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...21770.24861.0.25212.2.2.0.0.0.0.136.256.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.135...0i22i30k1.0.qNYOeKhIE3Q) That should tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: Why haven't you provided any sentence? Is there a reason? Did you look up "by hand/s" in several online dictionaries?

Answer (score 1):

**Human and Machine**

As you suggest, [*by hand*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/by_hand) describes something performed or made by human hands, not by machine:

> Though twisting can be done entirely [*by hand*](https://books.google.de/books?id=8MWx89GG3VMC&pg=PA30&dq=%22entirely+by+hand%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiP4cTDo5vaAhVLVSwKHTrrDUwQ6AEITzAH), it is faster and more even if a hand drill is used.
>
> In comparative operations, one [*by hand*](https://books.google.de/books?id=kageAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA31&dq=%22by+hand%22+garment&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5lcOVpJvaAhWN0qYKHWzPDowQ6AEIODAD) and the other by machine, the increase was from 400 to 600 percent.
>
> An accomplished seamstress, Baggett taught them how to sew, both [*by hand*](https://www.apnews.com/3447372b082b44a7a8bdb86383c45015) and on her old Singer machine.

**Human and the Natural, Divine, or Transcendent**

*By hands* also means made by human hands, but contrasts human agency not with the mechanical, but with the natural, divine, or transcendent:

> The God who made the world and everything in it—he is Lord of heaven and earth—does not live in shrines made [*by hands*](http://biblehub.com/acts/17-24.htm). — Acts 17.24, Christian Standard Bible.
>
> After having proceeded a considerable way thus, he arrived at a spacious chamber; but whether hollowed out [*by hands*](https://books.google.de/books?id=Fb5jAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA68&lpg=PA68&dq=%22hollowed+out+by+hands%22+natural&source=bl&ots=AxQZE0_2jK&sig=CjY0feQp8yYTJ-YH8gggtR7i6rY&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxjPGhmZvaAhUEYZoKHf0VDXgQ6AEwC3oECAUQAQ), or natural, he could not be positive.
>
> He wondered if it was natural or made [*by hands*](https://books.google.de/books?id=hPPH7CDj7HUC&pg=PT65&dq=%22made+by+hands%22+-circumcision+-temple&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwis7OG1oJvaAhXRbZoKHc-JB3AQ6AEIVTAJ).
>
> We are to see, not the likeness made [*by hands*](https://books.google.de/books?id=dqmnnLe17gkC&pg=PA143&dq=%22by+hands%22+nature&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT0d7Qm5vaAhVJBSwKHYO_DVQ4FBDoAQhKMAg), but its transcendental archetype; we are to take part in a communion.

**A Show of Hands**

*By hands* can also describe a means of voting among a group of people, more commonly *by a show of hands*:

> Maybe we can take a vote, either secret or [*by hands*](https://books.google.de/books?id=e2qZBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA303&dq=%22or+by+hands%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibsrPRn5vaAhWFQpoKHbR-AwcQ6AEISzAG).

**Conclusion**

A coat not made *by hand* means that the garment was machine sewn.  A coat not made *by hands* would have to be one produced by natural or supernatural, but not human agency.

Comment: There are examples from the first link, using the plural form, which say: *not built by "human" hands* that makes the meaning much clearer

Comment: I'm so much impressed by your detailed explanation. You must've spent qite a time and effort looking for the information. Now, from your exampleas I can conclude that  'by hand' is appropriate for the sentence given by me. Thank you and if you have any different idea, could you share it with me?